# Where to set LEIN_ROOT?

Tags: environment-variables, leiningen

When using `sudo lein run` (because some of the files changed by that command need priveleges) I get this message:

```
WARNING: You're currently running as root; probably by accident.
Press control-C to abort or Enter to continue as root.
Set LEIN_ROOT to disable this warning.
```

Any idea how or where to set LEIN_ROOT in order to avoid getting this message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `LEIN_ROOT=true` to the end of `/etc/profile`. For this change to take effect, enter `source /etc/profile` to a terminal. Then run the command with `sudo -E lein run` to preserve environment variables.
If you are doing this over ssh you would need to do all of the above on the server then add `source /etc/profile` to the start of the ssh command run on the local machine.

```
ssh user@123.456.789 "source /etc/profile; sudo -E lein run"
```